# Restore a firebase project from GCP, authentication not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

So I messed up.

I saw in the GCP console a couple of projects I didn't recognize, so I scheduled them to be deleted.

Turns out these were the firebase projects.

I restored them, but the authentication configuration isn't coming back. When I go to the authentication page, a banner appears "An unknown error occurred loading users"

Nothing is enabled. It's like I've never enabled one. I try to enable email/password authentication and I get an error "Error updating email/password"

Will this solve itself in a few minutes? How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restoration can take some time, I have seen it take up to 48 hours to restore a project - After 24 hours I would reach out to Firebase support which can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact